# Rendering a component after a transition - React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me with some guidance for next steps on my project. I'm trying to replicate simpler versions of animations from this site, https://www.signesduquotidien.org/, in react. That site is made with jquery. This is what I have thus far, https://rljho.csb.app/, and you should be able to go to the sandbox from that link as well. What I'm trying to figure out is how to go about adding functionality to the circle so that when I click on it, after the transition to the center happens, it renders the component that's linked to it. Any/all advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> after the transition to the center happens, it renders the component that's linked to it

Use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) or [Routing](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

In your case change `activeCircle` to a state and render conditionally the component you want:

```
activeCircle === "blue" ? <MyComponent/> : <DefaultComponent/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Would I be adding that line of code to the div or would I be replacing the ternary that's already there? I was thinking of going the routing/linking route but wasn't sure where I would be adding it in app.js or circles.js and if it's in circles.js how I would add the links to the divs.

Comment: Read the links there are enought examples